# Inherited constructors ignore in-class initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

I have a class defined like this:

```
class ASTConcatenateLiteral : public ASTExpr {
    using ASTExpr::ASTExpr;
private:
    Type type_ = Type::nothingness();  // Type does not have a default constructor
};
```

This works fine with Clang. GCC, however, gives me an error message that makes me think it’s trying to use the default initializer:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘EmojicodeCompiler::Type::Type()’

If I replace `using ASTExpr::ASTExpr;` with a public constructor like this (ASTExpr only provides exactly this constructor)

```
ASTConcatenateLiteral(const SourcePosition &p) : ASTExpr(p) {}
```

everything works fine.

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

> The inherited constructors are equivalent to user-defined constructors with an empty body and with a member initializer list consisting of a single nested-name-specifier, which forwards all of its arguments to the base class constructor.

So why doesn’t the inherited constructor work? If the inherited constructor behaves like a user-defined constructors, it should use the value provided for `type_`, right? Which of the compilers is right according to the standard?

Comment: This compiles fine with g++ 7.2.

Comment: @Holt Sheesh. No wonder I didn't manage to reproduce the problem, if it only fails with older versions.

Comment: @Holt I tried with 6.2.0. But in that case I’ll have to bump the GCC version requirement once again...

Comment: `error: no matching function for call to ‘EmojicodeCompiler::Type::Type()’`  That should go on a geek T-shirt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clang is correct. When [inherited constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) is used, the initialization should proceed as if a defaulted default constructor were used to initialize the object of the derived class, thus the [default member initializers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) should be used.

(emphasis mine)

> If overload resolution selects one of the inherited constructors when initializing an object of such derived class, then the Base subobject from which the constructor was inherited is initialized using the inherited constructor, and all other bases and members of Derived are initialized as if by the defaulted default constructor (**default member initializers are used if provided**, otherwise default initialization takes place).

Here's an example from the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.inhctor.init#1):

> ```
> struct B1 {
>   B1(int, ...) { }
> };
>
> struct B2 {
>   B2(double) { }
> };
>
> int get();
>
> struct D1 : B1 {
>   using B1::B1;     // inherits B1(int, ...)
>   int x;
>   int y = get();
> };
>
> void test() {
>   D1 d(2, 3, 4);    // OK: B1 is initialized by calling B1(2, 3, 4),
>                     // then d.x is default-initialized (no initialization is performed),
>                     // then d.y is initialized by calling get()
>   D1 e;             // error: D1 has a deleted default constructor
> }
> ```

Note that `d.y` is initialized by the default member initializer.

Answer (score 11):

This was considered by the GCC developers as a compiler bug, [PR67054](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67054), which was fixed in GCC 7.2.

[Their minimal example](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-7-branch/gcc/testsuite/g%2B%2B.dg/cpp0x/inh-ctor29.C?view=co&revision=251000&content-type=text%2Fplain&pathrev=251000) is

> ```
> struct A
> {
>   A(int) {}
> };
>
> struct C
> {
>   C(int) {}
> };
>
> struct B : A
> {
>   using A::A;
>   C c = 42;
> };
>
> int main()
> {
>   B b = 24;
> }
> ```

Online compilers can be used to verify that GCC and clang are now in agreement.

Note that in GCC 7.1, as far as I can tell, no wrong code would be generated. Although the compiler required a default constructor, that default constructor would never be called. Therefore, a possible workaround for older versions of GCC is providing a declaration of the default constructor, but not a definition. Perhaps even use an attribute (not standard C++) to reject any attempts to use it:

```
struct C
{
#ifdef GCC_WORKAROUND_PR67054
  C() __attribute__((__error__("No.")));
#endif
  C(int) {}
};
```